# Difference between abort and rollback?

Tags: database, transactions, rollback, abort

What is the difference between abort and rollback in transaction management?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean the commands, normally none.

From - for example - the [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-abort.html);

> ABORT rolls back the current transaction and causes all the updates
>   made by the transaction to be discarded. This command is identical in
>   behavior to the standard SQL command ROLLBACK, and is present only for
>   historical reasons.

If you mean the database aborting a transaction automatically, this is usually done when there is an irrecoverable error (for example a lost connection) and is also normally done by rolling back the active transaction.